# bibtex: editor field: how to clasp a none-name value?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

For compiling a bibliography I'm using BibLaTex and for managing the bib-file I'm using BibDesk. The names-sequence is surname before given name(s) separated by a comma. For example:

Müller, Peter (2011): XYZ. Stuttgart: Verlag.

For incollections it is the same schema, but with added editor for example:

Müller, Peter (2010): XYZ. In: Meier, Hans (Hrsg.): ABC. Tübingen: Verlag, S. 5-29.

For the cases of incollections I'm having the problem, that the editor value is not always a sequence of given names and surname, sometimes it's an association like "Deutsche Gesellschaft für Sprachheilkunde". This will be compiled as follows:

Müller, Peter (2009): XYZ. In: Sprachheilkunde, Deutsche Gesellschaft für (Hrsg.): ABC. Hamburg: Verlag, S. 12-51.

Is there a easy way to clasp the associations name, best in BibDesk with the use of brackets. Or where and how do I need to define asscociation names as not splitable?

Comment: Maybe "Deutsche Gesellschaft für Sprachheilkunde" should be treated as the publisher instead of the editor? Looking at the biblatex manual it seems all editorial fields are treated as name lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bib file try

```
editor = {{Deutsche Gesellschaft für Sprachheilkunde}},
```

instead of

```
editor = {Deutsche Gesellschaft für Sprachheilkunde},
```

Comment: yeah, that works! do you know a if-command to test the editor field for curly brackets? Because know I need to turn off the small capitals in that cases of editors.

Comment: @Matthias Katerbow I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. You could please clarify it.

Comment: okay, sorry! I would like to add a if-command like follows to my declaration of incollection: If the editor field starts with a curly bracket, than the value of editor field should not be set to small capitals (or should be reset to \textnormal).

Comment: @Matthias Katerbow That sounds like another question. If you can't find an answer on the net I think you should post a new question on this site.

Comment: okay, I will search for in another way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Matthias: As you have accepted some answers to your questions, please consider also to upvote these answers (this has to be done separately from accepting them).

Comment: oh okay, didn't notice that before. thanks!

Comment: @Matthias: BTW, you may also upvote (and downvote) other answers. Even answers to questions asked by others. :-)